# Append values to another spreadsheet when column W contains a number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to append the values in the NAME and POSITION columns to another spreadsheet but only in the rows where total hours column contains a number. The values should be placed in column `F`.

Here is my attempt:

```
var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var srcSheet = sSheet.setActiveSheet(sSheet.getSheetByName('109 Directs'));
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eKLEK58-2oegSmFsGgvUz6g50HwKqNjwAEsSnxJDdyw/edit#gid=0").getSheetByName("Direct Data");
var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
// Column 22 W
 for (var i = 22; i <= lastRow; i++){
   var cell = srcSheet.getRange("W12:W46" + i).activate();
   var val = cell.getValue();
    if (val !== ""){

      var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("A12" + i + ":W46" + i);
       var tarRow = target.getLastRow();
       target.insertRowAfter(tarRow);
       var tarRange = target.getRange("A12" + (tarRow+1) + ":W46" + (tarRow+1));
       srcRange.copyTo(tarRange);
    }
 }
```

In the attached screenshot, the only data i want copied is Fake Name 1, 2, 9 and 3, and the positions.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8EW4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that would be to use a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula in the target spreadsheet, like this:

```
=query( 
  importrange("...source spreadsheet id...", "Sheet1!A11:W"), 
  "select Col1, Col2 where Col23 is not null", 
  1 
)
```

Place the formula in cell `F2` to show the results in columns `F:G`.

The results of the formula will be view-only. If you need them to be editable, a script is indeed needed. It could be something like this:

```
function copyRows() {
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById('1eKLEK58-2oegSmFsGgvUz6g50HwKqNjwAEsSnxJDdyw')
    .getSheetByName('Direct Data');
  const data = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getRange('109 Directs!A12:W')
    .getValues()
    .filter(row => 'number' === typeof row[22])
    .map(row => [row[0], row[1]]);
  appendRows_(targetSheet, data, 6);
}


/**
* Appends an array or a value to the bottom of a range starting
* at the given column in the first row where the column is blank.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet A spreadsheet sheet to append the data to.
* @param {Object[][]} data The data to append. This argument can be a 2D array, 1D array or a single value.
* @param {Number} optColumn Optional. The column number where to start appending the data. Defaults to 1.
* @return {Object} An object with fields {Range} range, {Number} rowStart, columnStart, numRows, numColumns.
*/
function appendRows_(sheet, data, optColumn) {
  // version 1.7, written by --Hyde, 11 February 2021
  if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
    data = [[data]];
  } else if (!Array.isArray(data[0])) {
    data = [data];
  }
  const rowStart = getLastRow_(sheet, optColumn) + 1;
  const columnStart = Number(optColumn) || 1;
  const numRows = data.length;
  const numColumns = data[0].length;
  const range = sheet.getRange(rowStart, columnStart, numRows, numColumns);
  range.setValues(data);
  return { range: range, rowStart: rowStart, columnStart: columnStart, numRows: numRows, numColumns: numColumns };
}


/**
* Gets the position of the last row that has visible content in a column of the sheet.
* When column is undefined, returns the last row that has visible content in any column.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet A sheet in a spreadsheet.
* @param {Number} columnNumber Optional. The 1-indexed position of a column in the sheet.
* @return {Number} The 1-indexed row number of the last row that has visible content.
*/
function getLastRow_(sheet, columnNumber) {
  // version 1.5, written by --Hyde, 4 April 2021
  const values = (
    columnNumber
      ? sheet.getRange(1, columnNumber, sheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1)
      : sheet.getDataRange()
  ).getDisplayValues();
  let row = values.length - 1;
  while (row && !values[row].join('')) row--;
  return row + 1;
}
```

Comment: I want to paste the data on column Starting "F2" of the target sheet no column A or B how do I do that?? so I can move the data around that I copied from the source sheet. everything else works I just want to paste the data on a specific column that

Comment: Use `appendRows_(targetSheet, data, 6)`. Edited the answer above.